# cannot use ydlidar on ros2 rolling

Tags: ros, lidar, ros2

I downloaded [the official package](https://github.com/YDLIDAR/ydlidar_ros2_driver) to use YDlidar X4 in ROS2 rolling, but every time i run `ros2 launch ydlidar_ros2_driver ydlidar_launch.py`, the following error occurs:

```
INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ohmin/.ros/log/2023-02-27-02-37-46-155449-ohmin-13510
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1]: process started with pid [13511]
[INFO] [static_transform_publisher-2]: process started with pid [13513]
[static_transform_publisher-2] [WARN] [1677433066.231842522] []: Old-style arguments are deprecated; see --help for new-style arguments
[ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1] [INFO] [1677433066.236957516] [ydlidar_ros2_driver_node]: [YDLIDAR INFO] Current ROS Driver Version: 1.0.1
[ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1] 
[ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::UninitializedStaticallyTypedParameterException'
[ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1]   what():  Statically typed parameter 'fixed_resolution' must be initialized.
[static_transform_publisher-2] [INFO] [1677433066.238474174] [static_tf_pub_laser]: Spinning until stopped - publishing transform
[static_transform_publisher-2] translation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.020000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] rotation: ('0.000000', '0.000000', '0.000000', '1.000000')
[static_transform_publisher-2] from 'base_link' to 'laser_frame'
[ERROR] [ydlidar_ros2_driver_node-1]: process has died [pid 13511, exit code -6, cmd '/home/ohmin/ydlidar_ros2_ws/install/ydlidar_ros2_driver/lib/ydlidar_ros2_driver/ydlidar_ros2_driver_node --ros-args -r __node:=ydlidar_ros2_driver_node --params-file /home/ohmin/ydlidar_ros2_ws/install/ydlidar_ros2_driver/share/ydlidar_ros2_driver/params/ydlidar.yaml'].
```

according to [the tutorial](https://qiita.com/porizou1/items/57edeeda15bbec76a462) and [the video](https://youtu.be/ZRMbyPOTTpI), I have changed my `ydlidar_launch.py` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import LifecycleNode
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch.actions import LogInfo

import lifecycle_msgs.msg
import os


def generate_launch_description():
    share_dir = get_package_share_directory('ydlidar_ros2_driver')
    parameter_file = LaunchConfiguration('params_file')
    node_name = 'ydlidar_ros2_driver_node'

    params_declare = DeclareLaunchArgument('params_file',
                                           default_value=os.path.join(
                                               share_dir, 'params', 'ydlidar.yaml'),
                                           description='FPath to the ROS2 parameters file to use.')

    driver_node = Node(package='ydlidar_ros2_driver',
                                executable='ydlidar_ros2_driver_node',
                                name='ydlidar_ros2_driver_node',
                                output='screen',
                                emulate_tty=True,
                                parameters=[parameter_file],
                                )
    tf2_node = Node(package='tf2_ros',
                    executable='static_transform_publisher',
                    name='static_tf_pub_laser',
                    arguments=['0', '0', '0.02','0', '0', '0', '1','base_link','laser_frame'],
                    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        params_declare,
        driver_node,
        tf2_node,
    ])
```

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

When I execute `./tri_test` in `YDLidar-SDK/build` to test my lidar, it spins for a short time and eventually stops with the following error:

```
0. ydlidar
1. ydlidar3
Please select the lidar port:1
Baudrate:
0. 115200
1. 128000
2. 150000
3. 153600
4. 230400
5. 460800
6. 512000
Please select the lidar baudrate:1
Whether the Lidar is one-way communication[yes/no]:yes
[YDLIDAR] SDK initializing
[YDLIDAR] SDK has been initialized
[YDLIDAR] SDK Version: 1.1.4
[YDLIDAR] Lidar successfully connected
[YDLIDAR] Lidar running correctly! The health status: good
[YDLIDAR] Lidar init success, Elapsed time 624 ms
[YDLIDAR] Start to getting intensity flag
[YDLIDAR] Auto set intensity 0
[YDLIDAR] End to getting intensity flag
[YDLIDAR] Create thread 0x265FF640
[YDLIDAR] Successed to start scan mode, Elapsed time 1174 ms
timeout count: 1
timeout count: 2
timeout count: 1
0x265FF640 thread has been canceled
[YDLIDAR] Failed to turn on the Lidar, because the lidar is [Device Tremble].
Fail to start Unknown error
```

I also tried to run `python3 plot_tof_test.py` in `YDLidar-SDK/python/examples` to test if there is some mechanical defect, but since I correct baudrate and singlechannel, this python command functioned correctly.

The following is my ydlidar.yaml.

```
ydlidar_ros2_driver_node:
  ros__parameters:
    port: /dev/ttyUSB0
    frame_id: laser_frame
    ignore_array: ""
    baudrate: 128000
    lidar_type: 1
    device_type: 0
    sample_rate: 5
    abnormal_check_count: 4
    resolution_fixed: true
    reversion: true
    inverted: true
    auto_reconnect: true
    isSingleChannel: false
    intensity: false
    support_motor_dtr: false
    angle_max: 180.0
    angle_min: -180.0
    range_max: 10
    range_min: 0.12
    frequency: 10.0
    invalid_range_is_inf: false
```

Comment: your parameter file seems to be wrong. Can you add it to your question?

Comment: @ignacio I edited my question, adding ydlidar.yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a problem with the params.

I solved this problem by simply change the used yaml file from ydlidar.yaml to X2.yaml (the lidar I am using) in the launch view file then build the project again (just to be sure).
Then everything works fine.